# CreateWindowEx invalid X position once created

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I've noticed that once a window is created using "CreateWindowEx" with **x=0, y=0** position coordinates, window does not appear to be located in the the 0,0 corner of the screen. Instead it appears at the **x=*9*, y=0**.

- I'm using a single monitor.
- I'm not modyfing it's position anywhere else.
- Window is created as an overlapped parent window.
- When window is created, WM_MOVE get's called with x=8, y=31. (Those are "client-area" coordinates)

*(It's a bit strange that WM_MOVE y coordinate is 31px but in the screenshot you can see that it should be ~38px...)*

[image]

Window is created by:

```
mHandle = ::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, CLASS_NAME, APP_NAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, HWND_DESKTOP, nullptr, mInstance, this);
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? What might be the reason?

Comment: Windows have an invisible border around them for the drop shadow.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. That's specific to Windows 10, parts of the window's non-client area are transparent. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139450