# pywinauto capture_as_image adds unwanted borders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am using **pywinauto** to take a screenshot of a specific window.

Here is the code I use to take a capture of notepad ("Bloc-notes" in french) :

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().connect(title_re=".*Bloc-notes")
hwin = app.top_window()
hwin.set_focus()
img = hwin.capture_as_image()
img.save('notepad_screenshot.png')
```

And here is the result:

[image: screenshot]

The red "border" is the background of the window. **How can I safely eliminate this red border?**

I tried to configure Windows 10 in order not to show windows shadows (in the "visual effects settings") but it has no effect on the size of the capture.

When I look precisely on the capture, I can see that the left, bottom and right borders are 7 pixels thick. Can I reliably remove these pixels? What I mean by "reliably" is: will it always work, and work on other computers?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: While trying to find a solution, I found the following post giving a solution in VB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34143777/3909303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

```
import ctypes
from pywinauto import Application
import win32gui

app = Application().connect(title_re=".*Bloc-notes")
hwin = app.top_window()
hwin.set_focus()

window_title = hwin.window_text()
rect = ctypes.wintypes.RECT()
DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS = 9
ctypes.windll.dwmapi.DwmGetWindowAttribute(
    ctypes.wintypes.HWND(win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)),
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS),
    ctypes.byref(rect),
    ctypes.sizeof(rect)
)

img = hwin.capture_as_image(rect)
img.save('notepad_screenshot_ok.png')
```

And here is the result:

[image]

It has worked on all the tests I run (different windows).

Comment: Glad to see it will help the development of pywinauto!

Comment: BTW, you can accept your own answer. It seems correct.

Comment: I got an 'RECT' object has no attribute 'width' error

Comment: What instruction is raising the exception, precisely? ctypes.sizeof(rect)?

Comment: No, exactly this code is failing. I confirm. `pywinauto.win32structures.RECT` can be used for now as a workaround.

Comment: What does that mean? Has the ctypes.wintypes changed, breaking backward compatibility?

Comment: yeah `width()` and `heigh()` methods are missing on `ctypes.wintypes.RECT`. added an hackish fix.

Answer (score 0):

`Application().connect` can return a collection of windows.

Instead use `app['YOUR TITLE HERE']` or use [find_windows](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html#pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements).

From there you can capture the image without those borders.

You can find more info from the [docs](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=pywinauto.application.Application).