# Why does a window show a gap on the left side after MoveWindow(0, 0)

Tags: windows, forms, windows-10, vb6

I have multiple monitors.

I use MoveWindow to place a window on the top left corner:

```
Call MoveWindow(GetForegroundWindow(), 0, 0, somewidth, someheight, CInt(True))
```

It appears like that:

[image]

One can clearly see the gap on the left side.

To test what's going on, I move the window manually to the top left corner and call GetWindowRect.

Now it says that the window's Left is -8.

[image]

At first I thought that my screen was perhaps shifted, but all windows appear perfectly in that monitor and without any gap if maximized.

What might be going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: Had the same issue under different circumstances and it turned out on Windows 10 _(and above, I guess)_, it's not a bug, it's a feature, as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139450/getwindowrect-returns-a-size-including-invisible-borders).